# Why is bytecode verification performed in Java?

Tags: java, compilation, byte, bytecode, verification

From my understanding so far from [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187967&seqNum=2) the authors write the main purpose is to check if someone changed the bytecode. Because "a class file generated by a compiler for the Java programming language always passes verification". Is this the only reason we have a bytecode verifier, to prevent others from maliciously changing our bytecode?

Comment: Yes. That is indeed correct. I would not say it's the "only reason" though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the other reasons is that checking bytecode ensures that this is actually valid bytecode which jvm can run, it prevents jvm from running invalid code which will may lead to some unpredictable results. By disabling  bytecode verification, you say that you trust **all classes** you load to be bug-free at the bytecode level.

Useful [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/buck/never-disable-bytecode-verification-in-a-production-system).

When you have a big project with lots of dependencies you usually cannot say certainly if somewhere in this project or its dependencies you generate some classes, and even if you certainly now these places, you couldn't be certain that there are no bugs there. This code generating these classes can have bugs and you can end up with invalid bytecode.

Also even javac can have some bugs in it, so even it can produce invalid classes as output.

Answer (score 5):

> a class file generated by a compiler for the Java programming language always passes verification

In that form, the statement is not true. Of course, compilers are software and software can have bugs. Therefore, there is no guaranty that the class file generated by a compiler for the Java programming language is always correct.

Further, the correctness of a class depends on the other classes it interacts with. These classes must not have been changed in an incompatible way since the compilation, so if the environment you used for compiling is different to the environment you are trying to execute the code, these mismatches may cause the code to get rejected by the verifier, even if the compiler did everything right.

This already points you to the issue that besides intentional malicious modifications, there could also be code incompatibilities introduced by mistake without evil intentions. The verifier also protects against such scenarios and I would suppose, that this happens far more often than a real intentional attack.

Answer (score 2):

Because you'll typically not be the sole provider of classes you use in your program. You may use third-party libraries, and also third-party class generations, like some custom Java compiler instead of an official one. Or the official Java compiler can just have a bug that nobody noticed.

If as a result of it one of the classes you use, end up accessing variables that were never duly defined, then this is in violation of the Java language and Java platform guarantees, and Java cannot guarantee anymore that any other part of the program will behave as promised.

So the verifier checks whether you're in such a situation, and if so, informs you of it rather than let your program behave completely unexpectedly, and yes, potentially dangerously, rather than let you stay in the dark.